# Best Practise Coding for R script running in production

Tags: r, production-environment

We have a linux production server and a number of scripts we are writing that we want to run on it to collect data which then will be put into a Spark data lake.

My background is SQL Server / Fortran and there are very specific **best practices** that should be followed.

- Production environments should be stable in terms of version control, both from the code point of view, but also the installed applications, operating system, etc.
- Changes to code/applications/operating system should be done either in a separate environment or in a way that is controlled and can be *backed out*.
- If a second environment exist, then the possibility of parallel execution to test system changes can be performed.
- (Largely), developers are restricted from changing the production environment

In reviewing the R code, there are a number of things that I have questions on.

- library(), install.packages() - I would like to exclude the possibility of installing newer versions of packages each time scripts are run?
- how is it best to call R packages that are scheduled through a CRON job? There are a number of choices here.
- When using RSelenium what is the most efficient way to use a gui/web browser or virtualised web browser?

Comment: Your R questions strike me as still being too broad and vague to be easily answered. If this question is going to work, I think you'll need to provide more specific details.

Comment: The final three bullet points are distinctly separate questions.

Comment: Feel free to comment out `install.packages`. R will use what is available or produce errors to your chagrin if missing (unless you explicitly catch them).

Comment: Can someone help me out with why the down votes? I'd like to get an answer to my question, but have no chance if I just get down voted...

Comment: @Imo, happy to split into 3 questions

Comment: You've already received two suggestions for improvement: (1) split into separate questions and (2) provide more detail about your specific use cases; "the best way to run R scripts via CRON" is horribly vague.

Comment: I will close this and reopen as 3 separate questions. thx

Answer (score 1):

In any case I would scratch any notion of updating the packages automatically. Expect the maintainers of the packages you rely on to introduce backward incompatible changes. Your code will stop working out of the blue if you auto update. Do not assume anything sacred.

Past that you need to ask yourself how much hands on is your deployment. If you're OK with manually setting up each deployment then you can probably get away using the `packrat` package to pull down and keep sources of the exact versions you are using. This way reproducing your deployment is painful, but at least possible. If you want fully automated reproducible deployments I suggest you start building docker images with your packages and tagging them with dates or versions.

If you make no provisions for reproducing your environment you are asking for trouble, while it may seem OK at first to simply fix any incompatibilities as they come up with updates, and does indeed seem to be the official workflow from the powers that be, however misguided that is; eventually as your codebase grows that will be all you will end up doing.

Comment: Thank you for your helpful answer, but further to the comments above, I am going to be deleting this question and creating three new questions that hopefully will pass critical inspection, so would you be able to add this answer to my new question when it is up? Thx.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36925855/best-practise-r-script-running-in-production-package-versions