# Best Practise R script running in production - package versions

Tags: r, production-environment

We have a linux (Ubuntu 14.10) production server, and a number of R scripts we have written that we want to run on it that will collect data either from APIs or web scraping. The data will then be written to CSV files.

My background is SQL Server/Fortran and there are very specific best practices that should be followed with regard to production environments. Some salient ones are:-

- Production environments should be stable in terms of version control, both from the code point of view, but also the installed applications, operating system, etc.
- Changes to code/applications/operating system should be done either in a separate environment or in a way that is controlled and can be backed out.
  If a second environment exist, then the possibility of parallel execution to test system changes can be performed.
- (Largely), developers are restricted from changing the production environment.

**My question is this**: How can I ensure that the packages associated with my R code remain consistent and unchanging, until I choose to update them?

Comment: Never used it, but have you had a look at [packrat](https://rstudio.github.io/packrat/)?

Answer (score 5):

You could use Docker; our [Rocker project](https://hub.docker.com/u/rocker/dashboard/) has a few suitable containers to start.

Otherwise just use basic Unix sys.admining:

- if you don't want changes to R's package directories, make them read-only
- use maybe some tricks from HPC folks and use 'modules' (ie layers of symlinks or PATH settings) to make certain paths and directories visible or not

In general, the [Task View on Reproducible Research](https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/ReproducibleResearch.html) has some further pointers.  You *can* document in each production run what versions were used, and you *can* set up runs in such a way that versions can be compared to expectated versions.

But none of this is genuine to R -- these are all "Meta" questions for deployment.

Answer (score 0):

@Lev Kuznetsov has posted another solution using `packrat`, refer to his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36919953/best-practise-coding-for-r-script-running-in-production) to a more general question